# Unclear spam review audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I'm not clear on what exactly makes [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24188591/revisions) (from a failed review audit) "spam or offensive".

Some of the factors that went into my "Looks Good" decision were:

- The answer is from an established ~8K account with plenty of other answers, not a brand new account repeatedly linking the same thing.
- It's not a commercial product, but open-source (GPL) code on GitHub.
- I don't see any obvious connection between the poster and the project (i.e. not self-promotion).
- It doesn't seem to be link-only (it includes code showing how to use the library).
- I've recently flagged seemingly [worse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254025/how-to-build-a-3d-donut-chart/23896544#23896544) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119982/how-to-add-select-handler-in-guage-chart-and-then-get-the-selection-of-each-guge/24124390#24124390) (new low-rep account promoting a commercial product) as spam and had the flags disputed. This was a major factor in concluding that the answer is question was not spam.

For what it's worth, there are two other answers promoting the same library that haven't been deleted (one by the same user, one by a different user):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2142081
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24465881

If the first answer is spam, are those also spam?

Similarly, there are other live answers on the same question that are link-only:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895735 (broken link)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1896071 (full of ads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, it's because that user went on a rampage posting the same answer 16 times across different questions. He's *incredibly* lucky that the moderator didn't give him a -100 penalty or two for all that crap.

I'm not sure what exactly can be done about this as far as audits. The only way I, as a moderator, can prevent these form appearing further is to go through them all and manually clear all the spam flags. But that would also auto-undelete all of them, so I'd have to sit there and re-delete all of them again too. Bit too much effort, especially since the spam flags are kind of *valid*.

Comment: The posts will stop being eligible for audits once they're over a certain age. (I forget what it is. 30 days, I think?)

Comment: @Anna Good to know.

Comment: It hardly seems proper to use this as a review audit when the key factor (repeated posting) isn't available to reviewers. The fact that diamond mod failed a review audit of another copy that he himself had previously deleted (linked in the dupe candidate) speaks to the absurdity.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Shouldn't clearing the spam flags remove them as audit cases? I had done that for a couple of these, and I just went through all the others. I'm hoping that will prevent future audit issues on these particular answers.

Comment: @BradLarson It's supposed to, because it actually changes the outcome of those spam flags from "helpful" to "disputed" - so there are no longer any helpful flags on the post.

Comment: @BradLarson It would. animuson was saying that it'd be more effort than it's worth to clear spam flags on *all* of them (plus somewhat semantically incorrect) just for the sake of avoiding audits.

Comment: Oh well, did it anyways. Given that this is at least the third person to be tripped up by these audits, they were causing enough trouble.

Comment: Works for me. I was just providing some additional information. :)