# Feedback on audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I recently failed this audit in the Low Quality Posts queue. I'm wondering if I handled this incorrectly or if it is just a bad audit.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20492408

[image]

While the question and answer are both pretty bad, the brief answer does attempt to answer the question and is not a link-only answer.

My understanding of the review process is that if an answer isn't great, but doesn't fit any of the deletion criteria, it should be left open to be downvoted.

Edit: I don't believe this is a duplicate of "There is no shame in using “Skip”" because skipping does not allow me to improve my reviewing in the future. I'm seeking to eradicate any misconceptions I may have about the grey areas of the review process, rather than avoid them by skipping.

Comment: [The answer (10k link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51214927/2751851) had been deleted as spam by a mod. Closely related: [*Unclear spam review audit*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262175/2751851)

Comment: It doesn't appear to be spam, the link in the answer is relevant.

Comment: @duplode nope, another user flagged it as spam and the moderator deleted it (without using a spam flag).

Comment: @Glorfindel You are right; [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51214927/timeline) says "deleted via vote". Does that make any tangible difference on what happens to the answer?

Comment: Yes; the -100 reputation penalty isn't applied in this case and the IP of the user isn't blocked.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh, I see -- so if the mod thought it was clear-cut spam they would have deleted it with a spam flag so that the heavy penalties would be applied. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of the answer so that I can understand what your question is about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: @bhpi You did the right thing, and this was just another bad audit. There are lots of bad audits, but as a percentage, the number is not great. In other words, we see a lot of complaints about the Audit feature not working properly, but it adds value to the site (even if it is broken, which is debated regularly). The common advice is to nevermind, move on, and keep trying.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That answer received a spam flag from a community member, and I deleted the post, validating the spam flag and making this an audit case.

We get a lot of spam for registrars and related services, so we're primed to be a little more suspicious of short posts linking to commercial services in this area by brand new accounts. However, I didn't cast my own binding spam flag on that to destroy and then destroy the user because I wasn't entirely sure they were a spammer. I saw no obvious connection with the service they linked to, and they quickly provided another apparently useful answer in a different domain soon after that.

This answer has been used as an audit case three times since then, with your review being the only audit failure. That said, enough time has passed without this user causing problems that I feel safe in saying this wasn't spam. I'll clear the spam flag on this in case others are confused about the audit. The question will remain deleted, because it was off topic for the site.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What would the correct review have been in this case?

Comment: @bphi - Mechanically, a vote to recommend deletion or a downvote would have passed the audit. I tend to be a little paranoid about new members promoting domain services, so I tend to delete these when flagged. I now don't think this was an actual attempt at spam, just a bad answer to an off topic question, so I can see why it might not be a great audit case for spam. It could be argued that recommending deletion or downvoting this would still be the correct action for this, even if it wasn't spam, but I can see the potential for confusion.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware that downvoting was one of the possible options. I think that would have been most appropriate. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There's a set of postings from awhile ago that opening the post and taking the opposite action manually contests the audit and enough of them will make the post not audit eligible anymore. Unfortunately that can't be done for deleted posts.

Comment: @bphi There are no downvote buttons in the Low Quality Queue. Maybe Brad Larson got a small confusion with a different queue.