# How to handle meta questions that links to deleted posts?

Tags: support, meta

I saw this post: [Feedback on audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371979/6699433)

[image]

I got interested and clicked the link. Of course the post was already deleted. Since the question did not cite anything, this question is now useless for all <10k users.

- How should I handle such a question? Is it appropriate to vote to close for *"can no longer be reproduced"*?
- How should such questions be handled if the link is still valid? Maybe closed as *unclear what you are asking*? Or should it be left opened?

Comment: Maybe it is time to get to 10K .... ;)

Comment: Somewhat related: [*When should \[specific-question\] Meta questions be closed as “can no longer be reproduced”?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365618/2751851)

Answer (score 6):

It should be left open if the only reason for closure is that the post has been deleted.

You can request clarification, e.g. a screenshot or a relevant quote, in the comments, if you think it's relevant to the discussion or necessary to understand the question.

Many of these meta posts are either specific support/clarification requests so not that useful for the long term, or use the post as an example and can be understood without it.

<sub>For this specific example, a picture was already requested, but not added for 6 hours, so I've added it now. For posts with more traffic, someone often responds faster</sub>